# Assign a New Word Document to a Variable

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word, word-2007

I'm currently running a VBA macro in Word. Part of it requires creating a new blank document to run some of the work in. Right now, I just have `Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument` which I then refer to through `Windows("Document1").Activate`.

However, the problem is that if I want to run the macro more than once, it won't work because whenever it creates a new blank document, it will become "Document2/3. etc.". I basically need to assign a blank document to a variable so I can call it reliably. I know how to do this with documents that are already saved (ones that have a filename/filepath), but not sure what it would take for a new/blank document.

I'm currently working in Word 2007.

Comment: What if your call to Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument could return an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely no problem:

```
Dim oDoc as Word.Document
Set oDoc = Documents.Add(DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument)
```

Comment: You need parentheses around the arguments to `Documents.Add` if you are going to return a value and store it in a variable.

Comment: Ah thanks. I had my oDoc variable as a string, since I was passing it into Documents.Open(oDoc).

Comment: @DavidZhang On StackOverflow, you indicate "the" answer by clicking the checkmark next to it :-) That helps site admin to know a discussion has been completed, others who may have the same or a similar question, and gives the person who supplied the answer some points on the site.